# count number of occurrences of a variable in a child object in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I assigned a data that is returned from an API to a variable named `todayData`. There's a child object called `meals` which in it has a property `name`.

What I want to achieve is to count the number of occurrences in the `name` property of the `meals` object. 
For example, the meal `Rice` can have multiple occurrences in the data.

**DATA**

```
 [{"id":5,"referenceId":1189,"firstName":"Dan","lastName":"Daniels","orders":[{"id":109,"meals":[{"id":47,"name":"Fried Rice","description":"This is a  very sweet meal","image":"","mealType":"LUNCH","unitPrice":-20,"status":"ENABLED"}],"serveDate":"2019-07-11 00:00:00"}]}]
```

**JS**

```
let occurences = this.todayData.reduce(function (r, row) {
    r[row.orders.meals.name] = ++r[row.orders.meals.name] || 1;
    return r;
}, {});

let result = Object.keys(occurences).map(function (key) {
    return { meals: key, count: occurences[key] };
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

```
r[row.orders[0].meals[0].name] = ++r[row.orders[0].meals[0].name] || 1;
```

Since some properties are of Array type, index should be set.

**EDIT 1:**

Solution for data with multiple orders along with multiple meals. (Thanks to Bill Cheng for making me to consider general approach.)

```
let mealOccureneceCount = {};
  let occurences = this.todayData.forEach(user => {
    user.orders.forEach(order => {
      order.meals.forEach(meal => {
        mealOccureneceCount[meal.name] = (mealOccureneceCount[meal.name] || 0) + 1;
    });
  });
});
console.log(mealOccureneceCount);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const occurences = this.todayData.reduce((r1, c1) => c1.orders.reduce((r2,c2) => c2.meals.reduce((r3,c3) => { r3[c3.name]= (r3[c3.name] || 0) + 1; return r3;}, r2), r1),{});

const result = Object.entries(occurences).map(([key, value]) => ({ meals: key, count: value }));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Is there any advantage in using the nested reduce() methods in your code?

Comment: the data structure is a 3-d array... unless you are only interested in meals only, you may get rid of the first 2 "reduces" and replace it with ```this.todayData.orders[0].meals.reduce(.......```

Comment: Your code is obvious since multiple orders and meals data are possible. Thanks.